# Build python package using swig and setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, swig

I have a dll file that I am wrapping using swig.
Then I want to create a package to distribute the python extension.

The folder structure looks like:

```
- myPackage
   - __init__.py
   - my_interface.i
   - my_header.hpp
   - my_dll.dll
   - my_lib.lib
- setup.py
- pyproject.toml
- MANIFEST.in
```

My `setup.py` file looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages    
my_module = Extension('_MyModule',
                           sources=['myPackage/my_interface_wrap.cpp'],
                           library_dirs=['myPackage'],
                           libraries= ["my_lib"],
                           include_dirs=['myPackage']
                           )

# my_module = Extension('_MyModule',
#                            sources=['myPackage/my_interface.i'],
#                            swig_opts=["-c++", "-ImyPackage"],
#                            library_dirs=['myPackage'],
#                            libraries= ["my_lib"],
#                            include_dirs=['myPackage']
#                            )
    
setup (name = 'MyPackage',
       version = '1.0',
       author      = "",
       description = """SWIG wrapper""",
       ext_modules = [my_module],
       py_modules = ["myModule.myModule"],
       package=["myPackage"],
       package_data={"myPackage": ["my_dll.dll"]},
       )
```

I would like `setup tools` to run swig, create the python module and build the extension (create the `.pyd` file). Then I would like to have everything in an archive to publish the package.

To build the package I use: `python -m build`

**The problem I have is that with the non commented extension definition, the extension is not packaged in the archive.** I have no error message from the build.

In order for the build to work, I need to first run swig and then build the package.
In that case I use the commented extension definition.

```
 swig -c++ -python myPackage/my_interface.i
 python -m build
```

Something must be wrong in the `setup.py` file.

There is not problem in the `.i` file since when doing all steps manually, the wrapper works.